# Opennebula VM not persisting network config

Tags: networking, kvm, opennebula

I've created a VM with a VNET attached on Opennebula, after a while I changed the params of the VNET but those changes do not persist on the VM after my (physical)host is restarted.

I’ve changed the /var/lib/one/vms/{$VM_ID}/context.sh file but still no luck persisting the changes.

Do you know what it could be?

I'm using OpenNebula with KVM on a Debian8 host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while I figure out how to do this myself.

It seems that when the VM is started, the file `/var/lib/one/datastores/0/$VM_ID/disk.1` is attached as `/dev/sr0`.

During boot process `/usr/sbin/one-contextd` mounts this unit an uses the variables inside it, they usually look like this:

```
DISK_ID='1'
ETH0_IP='192.168.168.217'
ETH0_MAC='02:00:c0:a8:a8:d9'
ETH0_DNS='192.168.168.217'
ETH0_GATEWAY='192.168.168.254'
```

This info are used to export ENV variables (the exported variables can be found on `/tmp/one_env`) which are used by the script `/etc/one-context.d/00-network` to set network configuration.

OpenNebula doesn't provide a simple way of replacing this configs after the VM is created, but you can do the following:

- Edit `/var/lib/one/datastores/0/$VM_ID/disk.1` and make the required
  changes
- Restart opennebula service
- Restart the VM

Hope this is useful to someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the issue is that this functionality is not supported in current versions of OpenNebula. This will be supported in the upcoming 5.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

You can power off the VM and change most of the parameters(not network parameters as they are linked to a vnet) in the conf tab of the VM.

[image: VM Conf tab]

For a network-specific change only, you can simply log-in to the VM and mv the file /etc/one-context.d/00-network to some other place and your changes to the network configuration of VM won't be overwritten by the network context script.